# Add active Menu or Navigation class based on URL

Tags: javascript, html, class, menu

I've added an `active` class to my menu items. However my current implementation is adding the class to **all list menu items** as opposed to whatever the **current page** is.

Please let me know if there is an issue with my current code, and what I can do to achieve the desired outcome.

```
<ul id="menu_items">
 <li class="has-sub"><a href="/collections">STORE</a></li>
 <li><a href="/collections">RESEARCH</a></li>
 <li><a href="/collections">INFO</a></li>
</ul>

$(function(){
        var current = location.pathname;
        $('#menu_items li a').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            // if the current path is like this link, make it active
            if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        })
    })
```

`.active {text-decoration:underline;}`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Try this way, hope it will work

```
<ul id="menu_items">
<li><a href="#index">Index</a></li>
 <li class="has-sub"><a href="#store">STORE</a></li>
 <li><a href="#research">RESEARCH</a></li>
 <li><a href="#info">INFO</a></li>
</ul>
</html>

<Script>
 $("#menu_items li").bind("click", function(e){

 $("li").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).find("a").addClass("active")
    })
 })

</Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the URLs , All the Links are "/collections"

Comment: This helps, however now all links have the `active` class when I am at the index page